# Selenium test automation example using javascript fails "Element could not be scrolled into view"

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests

Running the example code provided on the following site I am getting an error that the element cannot be scrolled into view.  I have attached the code and error I am seeing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Your_own_automation_environment

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');

driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');

driver.sleep(1000).then(function() {
  driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.TAB);
});

driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();

driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
  driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
      console.log('Test passed');
    } else {
      console.log('Test failed');
    }
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

```
(node:78192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementNotInteractableError: Element <input class="gNO89b" name="btnK" type="submit"> could not be scrolled into view
    at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\automation_workspace\examples\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\automation_workspace\examples\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:560:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\automation_workspace\examples\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:486:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:78192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:78192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```